# Python If/Else Logic with File I/O

Tags: python, if-statement, file-io, io

I have a program that reads in 5 files, performs a "two sum" algorithm over the arrays in the file, and outputs to a new file if there's a sum of two numbers that matches the target.

I've got the logic to handle everything ***except*** if there's no match. If there's no match I need to write "No" to the output file. If I just add `else: f.write("No")` after the second `if` then it'll write "No" *for every pass* that it's not a match. I need it write "No" ***ONCE*** at the end of the processing, *after* it hasn't found a match.

Read 5 "in" files

```
inPrefix = "in"
outPrefix = "out"
for i in range(1, 6):
    inFile = inPrefix + str(i) + ".txt"
    with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
        fileLines = f.readlines()
        target = fileLines[1]
        arr = fileLines[2]
```

Output 5 "out" files

```
    outFile = outPrefix + str(i) + ".txt"
    with open(outFile, 'a') as f:
        f.write(target)
        f.write(arr)
        target = int(target)
        num_arr = [int(j) for j in arr.split()]

        for a in range(len(num_arr)):
            for b in range(a, len(num_arr)):
                curr = num_arr[a] + num_arr[b]
                if num_arr[a]*2 == target:
                    a = str(num_arr[a])
                    target = str(target)
                    answer = "{}+{}={}".format(a,a,target)
                    f.write("Yes")
                    f.write("\n")
                    f.write(answer)
                    break
                if curr == target:
                    a = str(num_arr[a])
                    b = str(num_arr[b])
                    target = str(target)
                    answer = "{}+{}={}".format(a,b,target)
                    f.write("Yes")
                    f.write("\n")
                    f.write(answer)
                    break
    f.close()
```

Comment: Hi, please reduce your code to a [mcve]. Where is your code breaking, and what is the error? You may benefit from looking at [ask].

Comment: I'm new to Python but not to programming. I can't reduce this more. There is no error.

Comment: I need to add logic that if there's no two numbers in the array that add up to the target number, it will write "No" to the output file. that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a variable -- let's call it `wrote_yes` -- to False at the top of the code.

Anytime you write "Yes" to the file, set that variable to True.

When you reach the end of all the processing, check that variable.  If it's still False, then you never wrote "Yes", so now you can write "No".